# Package tikz error: I did not find the tikz library 'braids'

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing, braids

The following is what I have. I tried to draw braids using Latex following the `braids` package documentation. But I cannot find the `tikz` library `braids`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz,braids,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{braids}


\begin{document}



\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[
rotate=90,
braid/.cd,
everystrand/.style={ultrathick},
strand1/.style={red},
strand2/.style={green},
strand3/.style={blue},
] {braid={s_1s_2^{−1}s_1s_2^{−1}s_1s_2^{−1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: The old `braids` package has been reimplanted as a Ti*k*Z library. You should install it if your LaTeX distribution is not up to date.

Comment: @SebGlav Thanks a lot. As shown in the code, I was trying to import the  ```braids``` package from the tikzlibrary but resulted in the error. I am not sure how Latex distribution works. Also, if I tried the syntax ```\braid[number of strands = 2] (braid) s_1;```, this works without ```\usetikzlibrary{braids}```.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? The tikz library version dates from 2019.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I don't know about TeX distribution but I just searched it and ran `pdflatex --version` on my terminal. This is what I got:
`pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
... ...`

Comment: That looks like TeX Live 2019.  I don't recall if the braids library made it into TL2019, but if not then you can download it from ctan.  Though upgrading your distribution to TL2021 would be a good option instead.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I updated my TeX distribution but I got the same error.

Comment: What distribution are you using?  Are you on a Windows machine or something else?  If using MikTeX then you may have to flag the braids package for manual installation as it is a tikz library so MikTeX may not recognise that it needs upgrading.

Comment: @user174967 Note: empty space and dash. I edited your file

Comment: @AndrewStacey I downloaded MacTex 2021 for the update.

Comment: @M.Ahmadi Thanks a lot! Could you explain more about what I should do for the codes? I didn't really get it.

Comment: @user174967 Put a space between (everystrand, ultrathick, strand1, strand2, strand3)  edit to (every strand, ultra thick, strand 1, strand 2, strand 3) and type negative one again. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compile with TL2020-2021**

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{braids} % https://ctan.org/pkg/braids?lang=en
\usetikzlibrary{braids}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[
rotate=90,
braid/.cd,
every strand/.style={ultra thick}, %Note: <<== empty space
strand 1/.style={red}, %Note: <<== empty space
strand 2/.style={green}, %Note: <<== empty space
strand 3/.style={blue}, %Note: <<== empty space
] {braid={s_1 s_2^{-1} s_1 s_2^{-1} s_1 s_2^{-1}}}; %Note: dash for -1
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```